# Alfresco Share forms: how to define a custom validation-handler for a non-mandatory field?

Tags: validation, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have already read the Alfresco documentation as well as the wiki, but still it does not get clear: what's the proper way to define a custom validation-handler for a certain field in an Alfresco Share form?

The problem is that the approach that I found everywhere in the forum always overrides the MANDATORY type, so the validation handler only gets called if the field is set to mandatory="true".

```
<config evaluator="aspect" condition="my:aspect">
       <forms>
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="my:property" />
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <field id="my:property" mandatory="true">
                    <constraint-handlers>
                        <constraint type="MANDATORY" validation-handler="Alfresco.forms.validation.myValidator" event="keyup" />
                    </constraint-handlers>
                </field>
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

But how to define a custom validation-handler for **a field that is not mandatory**? Or else, which is the correct type to choose/override? I tried [type="LENGTH"](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms_Developer_Guide#Validation_Handlers) instead, but this also does not get called when the user enters something in the form field and the field.

**Update:**

I have also tried Andreas' suggestion from the comment below, however, the validation-handler does not get called. This is my xml and function:

```
<field id="my:field" mandatory="false">
    <constraint-handlers>
        <constraint message-id="mandatory.field.empty.suffix" event="keyup,propertychange" validation-handler="Alfresco.forms.validation.metahead"/>
    </constraint-handlers>                      
</field>
```

Validation handler function:

```
Alfresco.forms.validation.metahead = function FormEditMetadataWebWorkflowExt_metahead(field, args, event, form, silent, message)
   {
    console.log('metahead!');
    return false;
   }
```

The above validation function does not get called at any time, neither when I change the value of my field nor any other form field.

Next, I tried to register the validation handler manually as I read in the Alfresco forum somewhere:

```
YAHOO.Bubbling.fire("registerValidationHandler",{fieldId: 'fieldIdOfMyField',handler: Alfresco.forms.validation.metahead, when: "onkeyup"});
```

but this only works partly. It does call my validation handler function only when **any other (mandatory)** form field changes (which is normal since the entire form validation happens when a field changes), but **not** when I change the value of **my own field ("my:field")**.

(And also, why would the validation handler need to be registered manually; I would think this is what the constraint configuration in xml is for.)

Comment: On 4.2.e, it works for me w/o the type attribute and w/o 'additional' registration of the validation handler (firing the event). Which version of Alfresco Share are you using ?

Comment: I'm on 4.0.2.9 Enterprise at the moment, which is the production system in this given project. I will give it a try with a later version.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the type attribute, so it reads:

```
<constraint validation-handler="YourCompany.forms.validation.yourValidator" event="keyup" />
```

If your function

```
YourCompany.forms.validation.yourValidator = function (field, args, event, form, silent, message)
{...}
```

returns false, the message displayed resolves to the value of `YourCompany.forms.validation.yourValidator.message` from the message resources (default mapping).

Comment: Thanks, but this also does not work / trigger the validation method, see my updated question.